# Cannot configure to deploy serverless stack to localstack

Tags: aws-sdk, serverless, localstack

I am using [serverless](https://serverless.com/) for deploying AWS serverless stack. (i.e: lambda, sqs, sns). I want to run before in local before trying to deploy to AWS. I have searched and see [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) suitable for my use case. Here is my step to deploy the system:

1. Clone project and run whole stack using docker. (command: `docker-compose up`)
2. Install library [serverless-localstack](https://github.com/localstack/serverless-localstack) and update `serverless.yml` in my project

Here is my config:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-localstack

custom:
  localstack:
    host: http://localhost
    debug: false
    endpoints:
    stages:
      - local
      - dev
    lambda:
      mountCode: False # Enable this flag to improve performance
```

After that, I deploy this stack using command: `serverless deploy --stage local`. But I always meet exception.

```
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 1 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 2 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 3 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 4 of 4

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  502
```

Here is my full deployment log:

```
Serverless: Generated requirements from /Users/hqt/Documents/avex/requirements.txt in /Users/hqt/Documents/avex/.serverless/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from /Users/hqt/Documents/avex/.serverless/requirements/requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python2.7
Serverless: Running docker run --rm -v /Users/hqt/Documents/avex/.serverless/requirements\:/var/task\:z -u 0 lambci/lambda\:build-python2.7 python2.7 -m pip install -t /var/task/ -r /var/task/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
Serverless: WARNING: Function crawl_twitter_accounts_api has timeout of 900 seconds, however, it's attached to API Gateway so it's automatically limited to 30 seconds.
Serverless: Using serverless-localstack
Serverless: Creating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack create progress...
..
Serverless: Stack create finished...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service avex.zip file to S3 (25.08 MB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Skipping template validation: Unsupported in Localstack
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 1 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 2 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 3 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 4 of 4

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  502

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     darwin
     Node Version:           11.6.0
     Serverless Version:     1.38.0
Serverless: Generated requirements from /Users/hqt/Documents/avex/requirements.txt in /Users/hqt/Documents/avex/.serverless/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Installing requirements from /Users/hqt/Documents/avex/.serverless/requirements/requirements.txt ...
Serverless: Docker Image: lambci/lambda:build-python2.7
Serverless: Running docker run --rm -v /Users/hqt/Documents/avex/.serverless/requirements\:/var/task\:z -u 0 lambci/lambda\:build-python2.7 python2.7 -m pip install -t /var/task/ -r /var/task/requirements.txt...
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
Serverless: WARNING: Function crawl_twitter_accounts_api has timeout of 900 seconds, however, it's attached to API Gateway so it's automatically limited to 30 seconds.
Serverless: Using serverless-localstack
Serverless: Creating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack create progress...
..
Serverless: Stack create finished...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service avex.zip file to S3 (25.08 MB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Skipping template validation: Unsupported in Localstack
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 1 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 2 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 3 of 4
Serverless: Recoverable error occurred (502), sleeping for 5 seconds. Try 4 of 4

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  502

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     darwin
     Node Version:           11.6.0
     Serverless Version:     1.38.0
```

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: I get the same error... I run sls deploy with SLS_DEBUG=3 and I can see that sls is trying to upload to s3 online, while I need it to use my local s3. I was not able to figure out how to fix it. The full log shows that it sets the TemplateURL: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/myproject-service-dev-deployment-bucket/serverless/myproject-service/dev/1575036075566-2019-11-29T14:01:15.566Z/compiled-cloudformation-template.json'